# How to set some config parameters for job in spring batch so that it can be used by steps and child jobs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

How to set some config parameters for job e.g input file path. My use case is, I have some jobs which processes data in input files and those jobs are triggered as a part of other jobs e.g.

```
<job id="jobA">     
    <step id="stepA" >
        <job ref="jobC"/>
    </step>     
</job>


<job id="jobB">     
    <step id="stepB" >
        <job ref="jobC"/>
    </step> 
</job>


<job id="jobC">     
    <step id="stepC" >
        <tasklet ref="steCTasklet" />
    </step>     
</job>
```

So here, JobA and JobB triggeres jobC. JobC process data in input file provided by JobA and JobB. How do I set the different input file path for JobA and JobB so that they are passed to JobC.

We can pass it as parameters to JobA and JobB but as it is fixed for JobA and JobB, I dont want to pass them as a parameter from outside.

Also the input file path should be accessible to other steps in JobA and JobB which do not trigger other jobs.

Also I am using spring-batch-admin so I do not have direct access to job launcher as it has its own.

Answer (score 1):

The `JobStep` can take a `JobParameterExtractor` as a dependency that will allow you to extract the job parameters you need from the `StepExecution`.  The implementation we provide is the `DefaultJobParametersExtractor`.  This pulls the job's parameters from the `StepExecution`'s `ExecutionContext` (you specify what keys to use).  This implementation also includes all of the parent job's parameters in what is passed to the sub job as parameters.

You can read more about the `JobParametersExtractor` at the links below. 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#external-flows
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobParametersExtractor.html

Comment: Thanks, I understand this. The question is about configuring parameters at the top level job instead of passing it from outside so that it can be used in top level job and cab be passed to child jobs.